# Keep getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error, despite it working throughout the program

Tags: python-3.x

For my programming class, we have to make a trivia program that has an independent point value for each question. To do this, I added the point as a line in the text file and have this line in the code:

```
points = int(next_line(the_file))
```

I also have:

```
if answer == correct:
    print("\nRight!")
    score += points
```

in order to add the points to the total score. 
This works all throughout the program, adding the points on after the player gets each question correct. However, at the end of the program, AFTER displaying the final score, the program says that there is a value error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 
I'm not sure what the error is, due to the fact that it works throughout the entire program, all the way up until the end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is the entire code:

```
import sys
choice = None
while choice != "0":
    choice = input("""
WELCOME TO THE TRIVIA CHALLENGE. PLEASE SELECT AN EPISODE
    0: Exit Game
    1: Trivia 1
    2: Trivia 2

    Choice: """)
    if choice == "0":
        print("You have chose to exit the program. Your loss.")
        sys.exit()
    elif choice == "1":
        fileChoice = "trivia1.txt"
    elif choice == "2":
        fileChoice = "trivia2.txt"
    else:
        print("You have entered an invalid option. You are being kicked off.")
        sys.exit()

    def open_file(file_name, mode):
        """Open a file."""
        try:
            the_file = open(file_name, mode)
        except IOError as e:
            print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
            input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            return the_file

    def next_line(the_file):
        """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
        line = the_file.readline()
        line = line.replace("/", "\n")
        return line

    def next_block(the_file):
        """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
        category = next_line(the_file)

        question = next_line(the_file)

        answers = []
        for i in range(4):
            answers.append(next_line(the_file))

        correct = next_line(the_file)
        if correct:
            correct = correct[0]


        explanation = next_line(the_file)

        points = int(next_line(the_file))

        return category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points

    def welcome(title):
        """Welcome the player and get his/her name."""
        print("\t\tWelcome to Trivia Challenge!\n")
        print("\t\t", title, "\n")

    def main():
        trivia_file = open_file(fileChoice, "r")
        title = next_line(trivia_file)
        welcome(title)
        score = 0

        # get first block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points = next_block(trivia_file)
        while category:
            # ask a question
            print(category)
            print(question)
            for i in range(4):
                print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])

            # get answer
            answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

            # check answer
            if answer == correct:
                print("\nRight!")
                score += points
            else:
                print("\nWrong.")
            print(explanation)
            print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

            # get next block
            category, question, answers, correct, explanation, points = next_block(trivia_file)
        trivia_file.close()
        print("That was the last question!")
        print("Your final score is", score)

    main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Another problem I have is with the way I did the sys.exit(), since it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: What is your exit condition?  Since it happens at the end, it is probably related to how you terminate the program, but without more code, that's just a guess.

Comment: I just added the entire code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Some of your lines are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error when you have a blank line. If you look at the error message, its telling you what the problem is (although it may not be obvious):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

The blank after `10:` is the clue, its actually a blank line in the file.

So, just check if there is a blank line:

```
points_line = next_line(the_file).strip()
if points_line:
    points = int(points_line)
else:
    print('Got a blank line when expecting points!')
```

Comment: If you're talking about in the text file, I've already looked over that several times and there are no blank spaces in it. Everything is formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes, but your `next_line` method is returning a blank line; if the actual line in the file only contains a `/`, then you are returning a `\n` from your method, which is a new line character; and in effect, a blank line.

Comment: I don't actually understand this very well, so can you explain? Because how I see it is that the next_line method reads the next line in the text file. So how could it return a blank line if there is no blank line there?

Comment: It will return a blank line, if the next line is just a single `/` character, because you are replacing this character with `\n`, which is a newline. If this is the only character in a file, its in effect, a blank line and more to the point of the actual problem, `\n` is not something that can be converted to an integer.

Comment: My text file also never has just a "/" as a line. The only time that is used in the text file is when the line is too long, and needs to go on to another line when being displayed.

Comment: You are trying to convert a blank, a space or something else that cannot be converted to an integer. That is the cause of the error. The source of the error is your `next_line` method. Beyond this, I leave it up to you to figure out why. Try something simple, like printing what is being returned by the `next_line` method before you convert it to an integer.